# Valve's game, Artifact Error! Create swap chain Unable query size of supported formats!

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, steam, opengl

I have Geforce 660M, tried to install mesa drivers, but I think I did something worst than good. If I switched on Intel from Nvidia with prime-select intel, the game started(launched it, but graphic was low and had no fonts, couldn't read anythink) before installation of mesa drivers and vulkan lunar sdk, now it launches but I can hear the game sound and I can only see the cursor, the rest is a black screen. The same happens if I use Nvidia as prime and put -gl in set launch settings in steam.

I use Ubuntu 18.04.1.

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 410.78
```

maybe it helps, when I use `vulkaninfo` I get this:

```
$ vulkaninfo
VULKANINFO

Vulkan Instance Version: 1.1.92

ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
INTEL-MESA: warning: Ivy Bridge Vulkan support is incomplete

INTEL-MESA: warning: ../src/intel/vulkan/anv_device.c:1204: FINISHME: Implement pop-free point clipping
Instance Extensions:
Instance Extensions count = 17VK_EXT_acquire_xlib_display : extension revision 1VK_EXT_debug_report : extension revision 8VK_EXT_debug_utils : extension revision 1VK_EXT_direct_mode_display : extension revision 1VK_EXT_display_surface_counter : extension revision 1VK_KHR_device_group_creation : extension revision 1VK_KHR_display : extension revision 23VK_KHR_external_fence_capabilities : extension revision 1VK_KHR_external_memory_capabilities : extension revision 1VK_KHR_external_semaphore_capabilities: extension revision 1VK_KHR_get_display_properties2 : extension revision 1VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2: extension revision 1VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2 : extension revision 1VK_KHR_surface : extension revision 25VK_KHR_wayland_surface : extension revision 6VK_KHR_xcb_surface : extension revision 6VK_KHR_xlib_surface : extension revision 6Layers: count = 16

VK_LAYER_GOOGLE_threading (Google Validation Layer) Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1
Layer Extensions count = 1
VK_EXT_debug_report : extension revision 6
Devices count = 2
GPU id : 0 (GeForce GTX 660M)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 0
GPU id : 1 (Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 0

VK_LAYER_GOOGLE_unique_objects (Google Validation Layer) Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1
Layer Extensions count = 0
Devices count = 2
GPU id : 0 (GeForce GTX 660M)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 0
GPU id : 1 (Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 0

VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump (LunarG debug layer) Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 2
Layer Extensions count = 0
Devices count = 2
GPU id : 0 (GeForce GTX 660M)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 0
GPU id : 1 (Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 0

VK_LAYER_LUNARG_assistant_layer (LunarG Validation Layer Factory Layer) Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1
Layer Extensions count = 1
VK_EXT_debug_report : extension revision 6
Devices count = 2
GPU id : 0 (GeForce GTX 660M)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 1
VK_EXT_debug_marker : extension revision 4
GPU id : 1 (Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 1
VK_EXT_debug_marker : extension revision 4

VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation (LunarG Validation Layer) Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1
Layer Extensions count = 1
VK_EXT_debug_report : extension revision 6
Devices count = 2
GPU id : 0 (GeForce GTX 660M)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 2
VK_EXT_debug_marker : extension revision 4
VK_EXT_validation_cache : extension revision 1
GPU id : 1 (Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 2
VK_EXT_debug_marker : extension revision 4
VK_EXT_validation_cache : extension revision 1

VK_LAYER_LUNARG_demo_layer (LunarG Validation Layer Factory Layer) Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1
Layer Extensions count = 1
VK_EXT_debug_report : extension revision 6
Devices count = 2
GPU id : 0 (GeForce GTX 660M)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 1
VK_EXT_debug_marker : extension revision 4
GPU id : 1 (Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 1
VK_EXT_debug_marker : extension revision 4

VK_LAYER_LUNARG_device_simulation (LunarG device simulation layer) Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1
Layer Extensions count = 0
Devices count = 2
GPU id : 0 (GeForce GTX 660M)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 0
GPU id : 1 (Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 0

VK_LAYER_LUNARG_monitor (Execution Monitoring Layer) Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1
Layer Extensions count = 0
Devices count = 2
GPU id : 0 (GeForce GTX 660M)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 0
GPU id : 1 (Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 0

VK_LAYER_LUNARG_object_tracker (LunarG Validation Layer) Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1
Layer Extensions count = 1
VK_EXT_debug_report : extension revision 6
Devices count = 2
GPU id : 0 (GeForce GTX 660M)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 1
VK_EXT_debug_marker : extension revision 4
GPU id : 1 (Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 1
VK_EXT_debug_marker : extension revision 4

VK_LAYER_LUNARG_parameter_validation (LunarG Validation Layer) Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1
Layer Extensions count = 1
VK_EXT_debug_report : extension revision 6
Devices count = 2
GPU id : 0 (GeForce GTX 660M)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 1
VK_EXT_debug_marker : extension revision 4
GPU id : 1 (Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 1
VK_EXT_debug_marker : extension revision 4

VK_LAYER_LUNARG_screenshot (LunarG image capture layer) Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1
Layer Extensions count = 0
Devices count = 2
GPU id : 0 (GeForce GTX 660M)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 0
GPU id : 1 (Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 0

VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation (LunarG Standard Validation) Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1
Layer Extensions count = 1
VK_EXT_debug_report : extension revision 6
Devices count = 2
GPU id : 0 (GeForce GTX 660M)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 2
VK_EXT_debug_marker : extension revision 4
VK_EXT_validation_cache : extension revision 1
GPU id : 1 (Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 2
VK_EXT_debug_marker : extension revision 4
VK_EXT_validation_cache : extension revision 1

VK_LAYER_LUNARG_starter_layer (LunarG Validation Layer Factory Layer) Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1
Layer Extensions count = 1
VK_EXT_debug_report : extension revision 6
Devices count = 2
GPU id : 0 (GeForce GTX 660M)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 1
VK_EXT_debug_marker : extension revision 4
GPU id : 1 (Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 1
VK_EXT_debug_marker : extension revision 4

VK_LAYER_LUNARG_vktrace (Vktrace tracing library) Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1
Layer Extensions count = 0
Devices count = 2
GPU id : 0 (GeForce GTX 660M)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 0
GPU id : 1 (Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 0

VK_LAYER_VALVE_steam_overlay_32 (Steam Overlay Layer) Vulkan version 1.1.73, layer version 1
Layer Extensions count = 0
Devices count = 2
GPU id : 0 (GeForce GTX 660M)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 0
GPU id : 1 (Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 0

VK_LAYER_VALVE_steam_overlay_64 (Steam Overlay Layer) Vulkan version 1.1.73, layer version 1
Layer Extensions count = 0
Devices count = 2
GPU id : 0 (GeForce GTX 660M)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 0
GPU id : 1 (Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile)
Layer-Device Extensions count = 0
Presentable Surfaces:

GPU id : 0 (GeForce GTX 660M)
Surface type : VK_KHR_xcb_surface
vulkaninfo: /build/vulkan-tools-1.1.92.0~rc3/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.c:1309: AppDumpSurfaceFormats: Assertion `!err' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by using `sudo vulkaninfo` in the terminal instead of just `vulkaninfo` and it shows all the information without errors. I don't know why I even need to use this command, but after I use it the Artifact launches without problems.

Comment: I worked! On a side note, this is bizarre. I didn't think that by running `vulkaninfo` it would work, but it did. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Running it with sudo is paramount! Thank you, helped me as well with Dota Underlords!